# Reduce RAM consumption when fetching data from ClickHouse to Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, clickhouse

I'm trying to reduce RAM consumption when fetching data from ClickHouse to Pandas dataframe. Now I have:

```
Filename: full.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    37     89.1 MiB     89.1 MiB           1   @profile
    38                                         def full():
    39    754.0 MiB    664.9 MiB           1       df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=conn)
    40    754.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return df


CPU times: user 1.25 s, sys: 280 ms, total: 1.53 s
Wall time: 1min 8s
```

and:

```
Filename: it.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    37     89.4 MiB     89.4 MiB           1   @profile
    38                                         def it():
    39     89.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       df = pd.DataFrame()
    40    661.8 MiB    572.4 MiB           1       iterator = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=conn, chunksize=100_000)
    41    813.1 MiB     41.4 MiB           9       for chunk in iterator:
    42    813.1 MiB    109.9 MiB           8           df = df.append(chunk)
    43    813.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return df


CPU times: user 1.37 s, sys: 367 ms, total: 1.73 s
Wall time: 1min 12s
```

Measured by [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/). **conn** is [SQLAlchemy create_engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html). Rows count is 712 300.

As you can see by time they are more or less equal. But by memory they are not. I would expect the **pandas.read_sql** result as **iterator** (when **chunksize** is defined) would have much more less size. Or this is quite expected and normal?

UPD. [pandahouse](https://github.com/kszucs/pandahouse) shows such results:

```
Filename: ph.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    30     78.9 MiB     78.9 MiB           1   @profile
    31                                         def ph():
    32    290.1 MiB    211.2 MiB           1       df = read_clickhouse(query, connection={...})
    33    290.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return df
```